# In NP-hardness, can any category reduce to itself? How can you intuitively explain which categories reduce to the others?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, p-vs-np

I'm trying to understand how problems in NP-hardness reduce to one another. As I understand it now, if X reduces to Y, Y is *at least* as hard as X.

What I think that means, and would like confirmed or denied, is the following:

1. Any category can reduce to itself.
   Ex: P can reduce to P. NP can reduce to NP, NP-Complete can reduce to NP complete, NP-Hard can reduce to NP-hard, etc.
2. Any category can reduce to a greater category.
   Ex: P can reduce to anything greater than P. NP can reduce to anything greater than NP, etc.

Feel free to brutally rip apart my caveman logic. Enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

While your idea is correct for certain reductions and is a good first intuition, it is quite vague and could be clarified:

1. it depends on the type of reduction: for example, it is unknown if there is a polytime **many-one** (or Karp) reduction from a $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem to a $\text{co}\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem, but it is known that there is always a polytime **Turing** (or Cook) reduction.
2. it depends on the complexity of the reduction: it is unknown if there is a **logspace** many-one reduction from a $\mathsf{P}$ problem to a $\mathsf{L}$-complete problem, but it is known that there is always a **polytime** many-one reduction.
3. it depends on the complexity class: for example, there is no real notion of completeness for the class $\mathsf{BPP}$, but there exist $\mathsf{PP}$-complete problems (for example $\texttt{MAJSAT}$).
4. you say "NP-Hard can reduce to NP-hard", but this is wrong in the general case: $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problems do not have the same difficulty. For example, $\texttt{SAT}$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, and so is $\texttt{SUCCINCT HAM PATH}$. But since the last is $\mathsf{NEXP}$-complete, there is no polytime many-one reduction from it to $\texttt{SAT}$ which is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.
5. you say "Any category can reduce to itself." but this wrong for some particular cases: the empty language and the universal language are languages that are in most complexity classes ($\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ in particular), but there is no reduction from any other problem to those. Note that the previous counter-example also apply: even if two problems are in the same complexity class, they can have a different difficulty (both problems are in $\mathsf{NEXP}$).

The only "natural" reductions that you can count on are (given $\mathcal{C}$ a complexity class) : from $\mathcal{C}$ or $\mathcal{C}$-complete to $\mathcal{C}$-complete or $\mathcal{C}$-hard (given that the hardness is defined using the same reduction you are considering).